# Fresh php7 installation isn't loaded correctly

Tags: php, apache, homebrew

After installing php 7 with homebrew I'm getting this message:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 171 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10): image not found

line 171 is:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

`php -v` shows `PHP 5.5.36`. I also tried `brew link php72` but got

> Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/php72/7.2.0_11`

What is wrong here?

Comment: php -v will only show you the version of PHP used for your command line - not used by your web server

Comment: could you execute from the command line "ls -last /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so" and show the result ? and a "file /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apache conf should be saved in httpd.conf~previous or something similar

make sure xcode is updated

then

```
brew remove php71
brew install -s  --with-apache php71
```

To configure the version of Apache you've now installed with Homebrew, you can edit the config file:

```
$ sudo vi /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf
```

If you'll be installing PHP 7.1 you can go ahead and add the line to load the PHP module into Apache. In the httpd.conf file search for the other LoadModule lines and add a new one below them:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Next, to map the .php file extension to the PHP MIME type in Apache, search for the other AddType lines and add a new line below them:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

To enable loading index.php as a directory index, replace DirectoryIndex index.html in httpd.conf with the following and restart Apache:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

then restart your server

[Install Apache with Homebrew](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/4fea3514fa09ef298b1f)

Comment: after reinstalling php works, but version is 5.5.36. how to enable 7?

Comment: Make sure that you restart your web server. Then open a web page that contains only : <?php phpinfo();   - it will give you the php version used . Is it still 5.5.36 ?

Comment: yes, it's still 5.5.36, but "php -v" returns "PHP 7.2.0"

Comment: http://www.websightdesigns.com/posts/view/how-to-set-up-a-local-web-server-with-homebrew-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Comment: i reinstalled one more time. now httpd.conf is here: **/usr/local/httpd/httpd.conf**. LoadModule line was already there, added AddType and DirectoryIndex lines. as a result http://localhost doesn't work at all. apachectl configtest returns "Syntax OK"

Comment: localhost:8080 is working instead, but doesn't see index.php located in DocumentRoot. what can cause this?

Comment: DocumentRoot was changed to **/usr/local/var/www**. and php7 is loaded correctly

Comment: Beside, I didn't explained how to set up a virtual host, as it wasn't part of the question, but according to your comments, I guess it might have helped you. You may find extra information in the link provided